# Integrating JPA with an existing J2EE architecture

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence, weblogic, entitymanager

I was hoping to get some feedback from those who have successfully integrated JPA with legacy type products. Recently our software team has been considering the idea of adding JPA functionality to our J2EE software stack. We have been impressed by the power and flexibility of JPA, but are having a hard time integrating it "cleanly" with the current architecture. Most of the JPA examples we have found online are too simple to be applied to our current architecture.

Our current architecture is deeply nested. It is typically 7-8 layers deep from the user-facing "managed" bean to the database layer (and sometimes much deeper). Our problem is that @PersistenceContext can only be used on ManagedBeans. We don't want to make all of these data accessor classes MangedBeans, as this would result in dozens if not hundreds of beans. Not to mention you have to do inject for each of those 7-8 layers in between, making them all beans as well. This simply gets out of hand.

One idea that we have tried, which is probably a bad idea, is to have a singleton that can keep track of the injected EntityManager, and then access it at any layer. However, we have seen issues with this when redeploying applications (I assume due to stale classes).

It would be great to get feedback from anybody who has done something similar in the past. Re-architecture at this stage of development is simply out of the question. Is there a good way to do this, or are we trying to fit a square peg in a round hole?

Thanks in advance,

Weblogic 12.1.2

JPA2.0 - EclipesLink

Answer (score 0):

I've done something approximately akin to the 'singleton' approach that you propose (although without using dependency-injection or a container-managed singleton).  What I did was roughly:

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //first, check for a cached instance
    EntityManager cachedEm = (EntityManager)request.getAttribute(Constants.ENTITY_MANAGER_REQUEST_KEY);
    if (cachedEm != null) {
        if (! cachedEm.isOpen()) {
            //somebody has closed the cached EntityManager; discard it and get a new one
            request.removeAttribute(Constants.ENTITY_MANAGER_REQUEST_KEY);
            return getEntityManager(request);
        }
        return cachedEm;
    }

    //no cached instance, get a fresh one from the factory and cache it for this request
    cachedEm = factory.createEntityManager();
    request.setAttribute(Constants.ENTITY_MANAGER_REQUEST_KEY, cachedEm);
    return cachedEm;
}
```

So I've got a statically accessible utility-function that can be used to get an `EntityManager` keyed against the current request.  That ensures that under normal circumstances all the processing done in relation to a given HTTP request will use a single `EntityManager` (there are also additional methods for creating ad-hoc/standalone `EntityManager` instances, for the small handful of cases where doing so is useful and appropriate).  The class containing this utility-function is not container-managed; it's just a vanilla static utility class.

I've also wired it so that the Spring controller overseeing the process automatically closes the request's `EntityManager` after the response has been rendered/written, meaning there's only a single point in the code where I need to worry about calling `close()` on the `EntityManager`.  So it's reasonably close to container-managed persistence, without bespoke container management.

Can't really comment upon how well this approach plays with hot (re)deployments (I rarely do hot-deploys in practice as I've noticed that they tend to burn through `PermGen` space even when everything else works as it's supposed to), although I haven't seen any specific issues with it.  Nor do I see any reasons why there would be.

If your container/web framework is one of the ones that tries to hide the `HttpServletRequest` away from you at all costs then this approach might be a little clunky (and/or you'll have to rework it to use whatever request-surrogate your framework gives you).  And if you do a lot of testing using mock-objects, obviously static utility classes make that a bit more difficult.  But in practical terms, the above code has served me very well in several different applications.